# Command to run two or multiple tests

Tags: command-line, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

How to run two or more tests from a single TestCafe CLI command.

-t "Test name" accepts only one test name.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-t-name---test-name

Requirement:

Want to run selected 10 tests out of 80 available in .js file.

Is there any specific command or pattern available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run multiple TestCafe tests using below command, for e.g.

```
// Matching different search patterns
testcafe -e -u chrome testcafe/tests -T 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3'

// Matching similar search patterns L0 and L1 using regex
testcafe -e -u chrome testcafe/tests -T 'L[01]'
```

Answer (score 8):

You're correct that `-t` will only match a test name, but `-T` (capital) or `--test-grep`  [will allow you to match a pattern](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-t-pattern---test-grep-pattern).

If the tests you want to run are grouped in a fixture, you can also run a [particular fixture](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-f-name---fixture-name) with `-f` or a [set of fixtures](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-f-pattern---fixture-grep-pattern) with `-F` to match a pattern (similar to `-T`)